# Lualatex code to select enclosed text from another file

Tags: luatex

I am trying to write a function that would select a text delimited by some symbols (*) from another file and print it. The following gives an error. What is the right way to pass 'text' to string.gsub?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}

  a *string enclosed in* stars

\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    for x in string.gsub(text,"*(.*)*","") do
        tex.print(x)
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `*(.*)*`? This does not select the literal `*` which you seemingly want to use as delimiter…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `gmatch` instead of `gsub`. And probably non greedy regexp `(.-)` if there are more then one match:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}

  a *string enclosed in* stars *two* 

\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    for x in string.gmatch(text,"*(.-)*") do
        tex.print(x)
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! To print in lines, how does one insert \par or \n so that Latex correctly transfer it to luacode? tex.print(x)\\par?Obviously tex.print(x)\n does not work since \n = ^^J.

Comment: `tex.print(x .. "\\par")`

Comment: If I want to include some commands like \footnote into the text processed by lua (I cannot find the answers on this site right now), do I redefine catcode for \ within \begin{luacode*} and then redefine it back within luacode or right after it ends? Is this the 'right' way (and the most direct way)?